# How to use parameters in routes with angular?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to use the routing through the ts code, but I am having trouble using parameters.

```
onSubmit(s) {
        this.router.navigate(['/search', {string: 'mulher'} ]) ;
    }
```

Routes

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: AppComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'categoria/:id', component: ListaComponent },
            { path: 'player/:id', component: PlayerComponent },
            { path: 'search/:string', component: SearchComponent }]
    }]
```

> core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot
>   match any routes. URL Segment: 'search;string=mulher' Error: Cannot
>   match any routes. URL Segment: 'search;string=mulher'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
this.router.navigate(['/search', 'mulher']);
```